# OnTouch() & onClick() Events for a VIew within a ScrollView

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview, touch-event

I am Having a 10 Image Views Inside a Scroll View

once the Image is clicked I want to perform an action

But when I am trying to scroll the Imags in the ScrollView Touch_down and Touch_UP together are considered as a click

Help me out 
I know the solution is easy 
But I think I am missing some Logic

I am Putting My Code Here

```
  public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {
        if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && getParent() != null) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(p_event);
    }
 }
```

In this ScrollView I have added an ImageView

Comment: Plz guys suggest a solution other than using a ListView

Comment: without code nobody can help you

Comment: Where is the code of adding ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

well, i'm gonna try to answer..
i think (in my opinion), you should use onclick only for the ImageView, so when you scrolling on the ScrollView, that ImageView won't get clicked..
here a sample on my code

on the **layout.xml**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ur_img_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:onClick="onClickEvent"
            android:src="@drawable/yourDrawable"
            />
```

then create the event on your **activity.java** import android.view.View, create a method similar to the one you use in the .xml file, (on the example android:onClick="**onClickEvent**")

```
public void onClickEvent(View v){
      //do your event here
}
```

that's it.

Comment: I have tried this Still The problem Exists Rememeber I am Using a customScroll View whose code is present in the Question